# Child pid XXXX exit signal File size limit exceeded (25) in apache error_log when invoking imap_open()

Tags: php, apache2, openssl, gmail-imap

I have php page where I open and close IMAP connection to gmail (for testing purposes):

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $hostname = '{pop.gmail.com:995/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
    $mbox = imap_open($hostname, 'username', 'password') or die('Could not connect to the server!');
    echo 'opened';
    imap_close($mbox);
    echo 'closed';
```

When I call this page, browser displays message that no response is received from the server. IMAP is enabled in php and `function_exists('imap_open')` returns `true`. I opened apache error log and each time I make a call to this page, message is added to log:

```
[notice] child pid XXXX exit signal File size limit exceeded (25)
```

I have looked all over the internet and found that this message is related to size of a log file being over 2GB. I checked all logs and none exceeds 500MB. I get the same result if I change `hostname`, `username` or `password` to any string. I don't know why I don't get any other message from php. How should I check what's going on and how to find out what's the error? Please ask if you need any other info.

My server runs on Slackware 11 and php version is 5.2.4 with IMAP and SSL (openssl) enabled.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you comment out the imap_open() call?

Comment: Yes, still the same. Browser returns `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.` and the same line in error_log.

Comment: Well, if apache receives a SIGXFSZ signal, it is clearly while trying to write to a file over 2 Go. Are you sure you checked all logs files (error_log, access_log, maybe a different php log)?

Answer (score 0):

If you've **root access** and this is a **cPanel** based server, you can simply run this command

```
/scripts/biglogcheck -v
```

This will list the log files that are 2GB. You should reset those file and it should solve this problem.